# How to clean up regular expression

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have the following regular expression in my python code and it's really long. Since python is a space delimited language, how can I clean this up?

```
matches = re.findall("((?:jan(?:(?:.)?|(?:uary)?)|feb(?:(?:.)?|(?:ruary)?)|mar(?:(?:.)?|(?:ch)?)|apr(?:(?:.)?|(?:il)?)|may|jun(?:(?:.)?|(?:e)?)|jul(?:(?:.)?|(?:y)?)|aug(?:(?:.)?|(?:gust)?)|sep(?:(?:.)?|(?:ept(?:(?:.)?))?|(?:tember)?)|oct(?:(?:.)?|(?:ober)?)|nov(?:(?:.)?|(?:ember)?)|dec(?:(?:.)?|(?:ember)?)) (?:[12][0-9]|[1-9]))",fileText,re.IGNORECASE)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you explain the logic of the pattern, please. What is the regex with this pattern supposed to catch ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`re.VERBOSE`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.VERBOSE) flag to break the regex into multiple lines.

Note that to use multiple flags you'll have to use bitwise-OR operator:

```
flags = re.IGNORECASE | re.VERBOSE
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to write complex regexes like this:

```
r"""(?x)
    ....
"""
```

where

- `r` begins a raw literal, so that the slashes are escaped only once
- `"""` begins a multiline literal
- `(?x)` turns on the extended (verbose) mode: ignore whitespace, allow comments

For your example:

```
date = r"""(?xi)

    (?:  # this is a comment
          jan (?: \.|uary)?
        | feb (?: \.|ruary)?
        | mar (?: \.|ch)?
        | apr (?: \.|il)?

        etc
    )
    (?: # well, how about 30, 31?
        [12][0-9] | [1-9]
    )

"""
```

Inline flags like `(?xi)` are more readable than `re.XXX`, because they are bound to the expression itself, where they belong.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want ?

```
import re

regx = re.compile("("
                  "(?:"
                  "jan(?:\.|uary)"
                  "|"
                  "feb(?:\.|ruary)"
                  "|"
                  "mar(?:\.|ch)"
                  "|"
                  "apr(?:\.|il)"
                  "|"
                  "may"
                  "|"
                  "ju(?:n[.e]|l[.y])"
                  "|"
                  "aug(?:\.|ust)"
                  "|"
                  "sep(?:\.|tember)"
                  "|"
                  "oct(?:\.|ober)"
                  "|"
                  "(?:nov|dec)(?:\.|ember)"
                  ")"
                  " (?:[12][0-9]|[1-9]|3[01])"
                  ")",
                  re.IGNORECASE)


s = "ght july 24 tiren august 23 hyu jan. 11"

print regx.findall(s)
```

result

```
['july 24', 'august 23', 'jan. 11']
```

Between brackets, the dot looses its special meaning.